# Devise rails can't update with CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise and i am trying to create a CRUD interface. So I did, however I can't seem to update or even access the form.

Here my routes.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
resources :myusers
```

Here myuser controller edit, update

```
  # POST /myusers
  # POST /myusers.json
  def create
    @myuser = User.new(params[:myuser])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @myuser.save
        format.html { redirect_to @myuser, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @myuser, status: :created, location: @myuser }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @myuser.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /myusers/1
  # PUT /myusers/1.json
  def update
    @myuser = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @myuser.update_attributes(params[:myuser])
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @myuser.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here my edit form try 1

```
<%= form_for @myuser, url: myuser_path(@myuser), html: { method: :put} do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Try 2 is this

```
<%= form_for(@myuser) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

For one does seem to work but it actually does not modify the data, it does show the Message that it was modified.

Update

Here my registration controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

I also have the registration helper

```
module RegistrationsHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

This is my parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Fx7uCaiLyyT3wwnL9GrZ8671oJVeuYxodN+vXqpbqIE=",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"jf_dufour",
 "first"=>"Jean-Sebastien",
 "last"=>"Dufour",
 "phone"=>"...",
 "email"=>"jf_dufour@....ca",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "admin"=>"Technician"},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Did you follow the process here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface ?  If you're not managing the password & password_confirmation params appropriately the process will fail

Comment: How do i generate usercontroller? Because that would be the only i did not do. I do have edit registration as follow

Comment: In your case you would put it in the MyUsersController (for which you already posted your create & update actions)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab here, and say that the `resources :myusers` is causing your issue.

Since your singular model is named `User`, you want -  `resources :users`.

Only issue is, this will route your paths to `/users/` if you want `/myusers/` I think you'll have to use singular routes.. I don't believe that `resources` allows you to specify a different url.

Answer (score 0):

Your create action looks okay, just be sure in the form you're including the fields `:password` and `:password_confirmation`.

Your update action should look something like this:

```
# app/controllers/my_users_controller.rb

def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])

  if params[:myuser][:password].blank?
    params[:myuser].delete(:password)
    params[:myuser].delete(:password_confirmation)
  end

  if user.update_attributes(params[:myuser])
    redirect_to my_users_path, notice: "User has been updated."
  else
    render action: 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: I just try however i am getting this error now: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I had params as :user instead of :myuser... See latest update, does that help?

Comment: No, cause i had them check as myuser, device can be a pain sometime

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?  Are you using strong_parameters?  I am using Devise in this way and it works very well in Rails 3.

Comment: The version is the most recent one just install it yesterday, so its 3.2.13